# How do I use the phrase "way back" properly?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Can I say:

> *Wish you a safe way back to home*

when I am trying to tell someone I wish them to return home safely? When I was googling, I saw that there is another meaning for the phrase *way back*, which means *long ago*. Because of that I'm unsure whether I am using it correctly in my sentence. Does my sentence sound ambiguous? If yes, how can it be rephrased?

Comment: "*[I] wish you a safe way back home*" is unidiomatic and slightly awkward. You could say either "*I wish you a safe trip back home*" (though a native speaker would more likely phrase that  "*Have a...*"), or "*Be safe on your way back home*". Yes, we also use "*way back*" in a temporal sense, using the ubiquitous time<=>distance metaphor, as in "*Kushan and I are friends from way back [in time]*". Having said all that, this question isn't really suitable for EL&U; it would be better placed on our sister site, [ELL.SE].

Comment: To describe a machine... http://archive.org/web/

Comment: _get home safely_ is the best way to say it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Way back is used for 'long ago'. Check [OxfordDictionaries's entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/way-back)

> way back (informal) Long ago

Your sentence sounds strange to me with those words in it. Don't use it that way.

---

*Probably*, you are confused with this -

> [*make one's way back (to something)*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+way+back) - to work one's way back to something or some place **as in**... I made my ***way back to the little town*** in the densest fog I have ever seen. I went for a walk and got lost. It took hours for me to make my way back.

So, read the entry and clarify your doubt! :)

Comment: Ironically, "clarify your doubt" doesn't make much sense, either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I believe "doubt" is Indian English for "question" (although, it's true that "clarify your question" doesn't really make much sense either, but maybe it's also Indian English).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [I don't think so!](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22clarify%20your%20doubts%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @ChrisDown [true that!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)

Comment: @Maulik: Yes I'm aware of its meaning in Indian English. But it's nonsensical everywhere else. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you didn't get me! It's at many plcaes and not just India. That's what the link says! :)

Comment: @MaulikV It has a totally different meaning in those contexts. In the links it means "make it clear what your concerns are", but here you seem to use it to mean "better understand something that puzzles you." The latter meaning is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply say *Have a safe way back!* if you mean to wish someone a safe trip back to the place from which they have come.

"Have a safe trip home!" is probably the most common expression.

In my neck of the woods we say things like:

Have a safe trip back home.

Have a safe trip back.

Have a safe way home.

Have a safe way back.

We're looking for a safe way back home. Many of the roads are flooded.

[Here's an attestation](https://books.google.com/books?id=lpuXAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22have%20a%20safe%20trip%20back%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EdBIVe7KHoGUNuG8gbAJ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22have%20a%20safe%20trip%20back%22&f=false) of "Have a safe trip back":

And [here's an attestation](http://www.dscej.org/index.php/community-outreach-initiatives/a-safe-way-back-home/156-a-safe-way-back-home) of "a safe way back home".

In my AmE dialect, "way" can mean both "route" and "trip/journey".

Comment: That sounds strange.

Comment: Maybe it's an Americanism.  It's idiomatic AmE where I'm from.

Comment: "Safe trip" sounds better.

Comment: As I said, "safe trip" is probably most common expression, but what "sounds better" depends on what one is used to hearing.

Comment: "Safe home" is an informal expression- perhaps regional.

Comment: I have never heard the expression "safe home" to mean "have a safe trip home".  Is that what you meant?

Comment: I've heard "[get] home safe", but not "safe home".

Comment: @Random832 Yes, me either

Comment: I don't think I've heard *have a ____ way back (place)* in any part of the US I know. It sounds strange to me, too.

Comment: Hmmm that *safe way back home* seems to mean *a safe route back home*, not *a safe journey back home* ...

Comment: @Araucaria: What does it mean when we say "I hope you *make your way home* safely"?

Comment: @TRomano Ah, but *make your way* is an idiom ;) You can't say *I had a nice way to work today*, for example.

Comment: @TRomano But I just meant the link you gave not the expression in general. In my version of English *way* can't mean that, but it's completely possible that it can in some others. I'm just saying I don't think it means that in the attested link you gave.

Answer (score 3):

The use of an article (i.e. "**a** ... way back" in your sentence) makes it unambiguous. The phrase "way back" referring to a time long ago is an adjective phrase and does not accept an article - or, for example, a possessive pronoun, as in "my way back" in Maulik V's example.

I should note, though, that the way somewhere generally refers to the *route*, not to one specific trip. I think this is the reason the others are reading your sentence as being awkward. And I don't know about other dialects, but "back to home" is incorrect for American English, and should be "back to your home" or "back home".

Answer (score 2):

"way back" is an idiomatic expression for "long time ago", short for "a long way back in time". For example: "When did you meet Joe for the first time? " "That was way back when I still was a teenager".

In your case, you are using by coincidence the word "way" followed by the word "back". You could have said "wish you a safe journey back home", or "wish you a safe travel back home".  It has nothing to do with the idiomatic expression and is fine to use.

Dan Bron's suggestions are slightly better, but not to a degree where your sentence would be wrong. "Wish you a save way back home" sounds maybe a bit too worried that something could go wrong. Of course if you are a bit too worried then the sentence is exactly correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It is really comprehensible. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *way back* has two primary meanings, as others have pointed out.

Using *way back* can be used to refer to a long time ago, such as "way back when." In this instance *way* is describing the word *back* as being very far back.

> How far back was it? It was *way* back.

This meaning could also be applied to distance, meaning that something was a very long distance back on a path. Using *way* in this sense is fairly colloquial, not often found in formal writing.

---

The other use of *way back* is to refer to a specific path taken. In this case *back* is modifying the noun *way*, and often includes a destination.

> Which way did he take? He took the way *back* (to the house).

This implies that the path in question has already been traveled once, but you are now returning.

---

Your case more closely relates to the second definition, though most people would not use it that way. Instead, I would simply say

> Have a safe trip home!